# How to get the authentication token for IBM watson STT service?

Tags: ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am trying to use the Watson Speech To Text service which needs the following command for the websocket Interface as per the [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/websockets.html#websockets)

```
var token = {authentication-token};
var wsURI = 'wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize'
+ '?watson-token=' + token
+ '&model=es-ES_BroadbandModel';
```

I have tried this to get the `{authentication-token}` using curl command on terminal

```
curl -X GET --user "apikey:{apikey}" "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api"
```

The above command yields

> Error: {"code":401,"error":"Unauthorized","description":"ERCD250-LDAP-DN-AUTHERR"}

Couldn't find proper documentation for this including several posts which seem to be out of scope after the [recent changes](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/release-notes.html#limitations) made by IBM watson team.

**Question:** How do I get the `authentication-token` for connecting to the watson web socket properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `authentication-token` you need to run the following **cURL command**. This can be included in your program prior to the connection (websocket handshake).

```
curl -k -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header "Accept: application/json" --data-urlencode "grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey" --data-urlencode "apikey={your apikey}" "https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token"
```

Follow this link for more details - https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/getting-started-iam.html

For C++ users - You may include this as below

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

main(){
    //step 1- Initialise curl library
    //step 2- Set header
              curl_slist_append(headers,"Accept: application/json");
    //step 3- Set Post request data
              curl_slist_append(postdata,"grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey&apikey={my apikey}");
    //step 4- setup cURL request
          curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token");
          curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
          curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postdata);
/*Write callbacks to use the response in your authentication*/

          res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_slist_free_all(headers);
    // always cleanup
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

inside [callback](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) take a variable `token` to hold the parsed response

```
token = "Bearer<space><ParsedResponse>";
```

This string should be used as the **request header** for **websoket handshake**

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the **Speech to Text** API docs,

> You cannot use JavaScript to call the WebSocket interface from a
>   browser. The watson-token parameter that is available with the
>   **/v1/recognize method does not accept IAM tokens or API keys**. For
>   information about working around this limitation, see the [Release
>   notes](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/speech-to-text/release-notes.html#release-notes).

Here's the known limitation,

> The Speech to Text service has the following known limitation.
>
> Service instances that use IAM authentication cannot currently use
>   JavaScript to call the Speech to Text WebSocket interface. This
>   limitation applies to any application (such as the service demo) that
>   uses JavaScript to make WebSocket calls from a browser. WebSocket
>   calls that are made with other languages can use IAM tokens or API
>   keys. To work around this limitation, you can do the following:
>
> Call the WebSocket interface from outside of a browser. You can call
>   the interface from any language that supportsthe  WebSockets. Refer to
>   information in The WebSocket interface for guidance when working with
>   another language.
>
> **The Watson SDKs provide the simplest way to call the WebSocket
>   interface from another language. The SDKs accept an API key and manage
>   the lifecycle of the tokens.** For information about using the WebSocket
>   interface with the Node.js, Java, Python, and Ruby SDKs, see the [API reference](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?language=node#recognize-audio-websockets-).
>
> Use the synchronous or asynchronous HTTP interfaces to perform speech
>   recognition.

If you have an old Speech to Text service with cloud foundry credentials (username and password), you can make a Curl request for the `watson-token` like this

```
curl -u {USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api"
```

Even this is documented in the API docs under **watson-token** parameter under Curl

> Provides an authentication token for the service. Use a token that is
>   based on Cloud Foundry service credentials. Do not pass an IAM access
>   token or API key with this parameter.

**Update:** The WebSocket interface cannot be called from curl. Use a client-side scripting language to call the interface. You can find the code samples for streaming the audio in each of the programming languages SDKs like this example from Python SDK - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/microphone-speech-to-text.py

**UPDATE 2019-02-09**

According to the release documentation it is now again possible to authenticate to the websocket API from the browser. See: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/speech-to-text/release-notes.html#release-notes for release 28 January 2019.
However, getting an authentication token using your API key is NOT possible from the browser (prevented by CORG for security reasons).
So to make this work:
- get an api token for dallas (did not get it to work for other regions, looks like the lib is hardcoded set to the dallas server)
- use a backend application to get an authentication token using your api key
- use the authentication token straight from the browser using the speech-javascript-sdk

Comment: Hi @VidyasagarMachupalli Thanks for the input.

Comment: Hi @VidyasagarMachupalli I have gone through the above stated documentation, and I couldnot get the service to work for me due to **"authentication fail"**. I am not an old user, I have hardly started using this service from last month. I have done the STT for audio files (saved in the computer) using `apikey` as `curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}"`.  Now I want to use streaming audio input instead of an audio file. For this the document says I need to open the connection using `wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?watson-token={token}`  How do I get this **token**

Comment: @RohanChawhan I updated my answer with more information related to usage of curl.

Comment: I am not using curl for websocket interface.  I am using the boost library for that. But to connect to the "host" I need to provide the authentication token.  So my question here is "How do I get my authentication token? _[reference](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/202739/which-api-to-invoke-to-get-authentication-token-fo/)_

Comment: As clearly mentioned in the answer, if you want to use an API key, you should use a client programming language code/SDK. The supported programming languages as per the API docs are Java, Node, Python etc., You also have SDKs to help you with streaming audio using your API key. See the example in my updated answer above.

Comment: I am using C++ to use my PC as the client. I need to connect to the `host = "wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"` For this I need the authentication token. So the host url would look like `host = "wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"?watson-token={token}`. I don't have the "token". Do you have any link to a sample project in C++ for this application?

Comment: I am still running behind this issue. **Can I get some help here?** There is a language constraint (C++) and the examples given do not clarify my doubt. Is there an SDK example using C++?