# How can I obtain tokens for IBM Watson's Text-to-Speech service?

Tags: token, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-discovery, watson-text-to-speech

we are creating a medical chatbot that utilizes Watson Assistant and Discovery using OpenWhisk. We would now like to be able to use speech-to-text and text-to-speech, but are having trouble obtaining tokens for the synthesize() function. Right now, we are using the command

```
curl -u "apikey:apikey" --output token "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api"
```

but we are getting

```
{"code":401,"error":"Unauthorized","description":"ERCD250-LDAP-DN-AUTHERR"}
```

as an output. Could someone help point us in the right direction?

Comment: Tried this? https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/getting-started-iam.html#iam It has the steps

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53670666/how-to-get-the-authentication-token-for-ibm-watson-stt-service

Answer (score 1):

Tip: To see all your created app here.
https://console.bluemix.net/dashboard/apps

Did you input the api key ? 
[image]
curl -u "apikey:**apikey**" --output token "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api"