# How to connect to particular endpoint on "wss" [IBM Watson]

Tags: c++, ssl, websocket, ibm-watson, api-key

I am using the boost library to connect to IBM web-server (speech to text).

And I am stuck at web-socket handshaking stage. of the code. I have referred to the [Web-socket async SSL client example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async-ssl/websocket_client_async_ssl.cpp).

**Here is the code (similar as the above example with a few debug `cout` in between)**: Aim is to connect to `wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?apikey={my apikey}`

```
// Report a failure
void
fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what)
{
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    tcp::resolver resolver_;
    websocket::stream<ssl::stream<tcp::socket>> ws_;
    beast::multi_buffer buffer_;
    std::string host_;
    std::string text_;

public:
    // Resolver and socket require an io_context
    explicit
    session(net::io_context& ioc, ssl::context& ctx)
        : resolver_(ioc)
        , ws_(ioc, ctx)
    {
    }

    // Start the asynchronous operation
    void run(char const* host, char const* port, char const* text)
    {
        // Save these for later
        host_ = host;
        text_ = text;

        std::cout<< "Successfully reached: run operation:" << __LINE__<<" Resolving"<<std::endl;
        // Look up the domain name
        resolver_.async_resolve(
            host,
            port,
            std::bind(&session::on_resolve, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
    }

    void on_resolve(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type results)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "resolve");

        std::cout<< "Successfully reached: resolve operation:" << __LINE__<<" Resolving"<<std::endl;
        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        net::async_connect(
            ws_.next_layer().next_layer(),
            results.begin(),
            results.end(),
            std::bind(&session::on_connect, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void on_connect(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "connect");

        std::cout<< "Successfully reached: handshaking operation:" << __LINE__<<" Handshaking"<<std::endl;
        // Perform the SSL handshake
        ws_.next_layer().async_handshake(ssl::stream_base::client, std::bind(&session::on_ssl_handshake, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void on_ssl_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "ssl_handshake");

        std::cout<< "Successfully reached: handshaking operation:" << __LINE__<<" Handshaking"<<std::endl;
        // Perform the websocket handshake
        ws_.async_handshake(host_, "/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize", std::bind( &session::on_handshake, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void on_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        std::cout<< "Successfully reached: handshaking operation:" << __LINE__<<" Handshaking"<<std::endl;
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "handshake");

        std::cout<< "Successfully reached: handshaking operation:" << __LINE__<<" Send message"<<std::endl;
        // Send the message
        ws_.async_write(net::buffer(text_), std::bind(&session::on_write, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1,
                                                                                            std::placeholders::_2));
    }

    void
    on_write(
        beast::error_code ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "write");

        // Read a message into our buffer
        ws_.async_read(
            buffer_,
            std::bind(
                &session::on_read,
                shared_from_this(),
                std::placeholders::_1,
                std::placeholders::_2));
    }

    void
    on_read(
        beast::error_code ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "read");

        // Close the WebSocket connection
        ws_.async_close(websocket::close_code::normal,
            std::bind(
                &session::on_close,
                shared_from_this(),
                std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void
    on_close(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "close");

        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully

        // The buffers() function helps print a ConstBufferSequence
        std::cout << beast::buffers(buffer_.data()) << std::endl;
    }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto const host = "stream.watsonplatform.net";
    auto const port = "443";
    auto const text = "speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize";//apikey={my apikey}

    std::cout<< "Successfully reached: Main function"<<std::endl;
    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc;

    // The SSL context is required, and holds certificates
    ssl::context ctx{ssl::context::sslv23_client};
    std::cout<< "Successfully reached: SSL context to hold certificates"<<std::endl;

    // This holds the root certificate used for verification
    load_root_certificates(ctx);

    std::cout<< "Successfully reached: Loading root certificates - Goes to Launch asyn operation"<<std::endl;
    // Launch the asynchronous operation
    std::make_shared<session>(ioc, ctx)->run(host, port, text);

    std::cout<< "Successfully reached: Launched asyn operation"<<std::endl;
    // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
    // the socket is closed.
    ioc.run();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am getting the output on console as :

> Successfully reached: Main function
>
> Successfully reached: SSL context to hold certificates
>
> Successfully reached: Loading root certificates - Goes to Launch asyn
>   operation
>
> Successfully reached: run operation:71 Resolving
>
> Successfully reached: Launched asyn operation
>
> Successfully reached: resolve operation:84 Resolving
>
> Successfully reached: handshaking operation:98 Handshaking
>
> Successfully reached: handshaking operation:108 Handshaking
>
> Successfully reached: handshaking operation:115 Handshaking
>
> handshake: The WebSocket handshake was declined by the remote peer

Here I am A bit confused where the error has occured **`on_ssl_handshake`** or **`on_handshake`** and how to accomplish the above "Aim".

Kindly provide a resolution.

regards and Thanks

Wireshark entries:
[image: Wireshark screenshot]

Comment: Are you including your API key in the actual code?

Comment: No. I am not sure where would it go in the code!

Comment: But you gave the correct string yourself, in the question: `/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?apikey={my apikey}`

Comment: Here you need to add the apikey to the target:
`ws_.async_handshake(host_, "/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize", std::bind( &session::on_handshake, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1));`

Comment: Hi @VinnieFalco I have tried what you said like this `ws_.async_handshake(host_, "/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?apikey={my apikey}", std::bind( &session::on_handshake, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1));` This gives the same output as there in the question above.

Comment: @VinnieFalco should there be  an `=` or `:` sign between `apikey={my apikey}`? Well I tried both & they didn't work. Also if I am mentioning the string `"speech-to-text/api...{my apikey}"` here `ws_.async_handshake()` then what should be mentioned in the `auto const text = "..."` in the main?

Comment: @VinnieFalco Please see the updated post. I have added wireshark entries. If it helps.

Comment: @VinnieFalco **UPDATE** apparently the apikey is not going to work here. I followed the steps [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/getting-started-iam.html) to generate the token. Now I'm fighting to send it as a request header. I am looking into [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream/async_handshake_ex/overload1.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh it worked!

the problem was with the `ws_.async_handshake` instead I had to use the `ws_.async_handshake_ex` as below:

```
ws_.async_handshake_ex(host_, "/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize",[](request_type& reqHead){reqHead.insert(http::field::authorization,"Bearer {my token}");},std::bind( &session::on_handshake, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1));
```

The `token` is not the same as `apikey`. It needs to be generated as given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53670666/how-to-get-the-authentication-token-for-ibm-watson-stt-service)

**Clarification:**

The url is `"stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"`
and the `authentication token` goes as request header.