# Unable to find the reason for "Broken Pipe" error while sending continuous data chunks through Beast websocket

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, boost-beast, beast

I am working on **streaming audio recognition** with IBM Watson speech to text web service API. I have created a web-socket with boost *(beast 1.68.0)* library in C++(std 11).

I have successfully connected to the IBM server, and want to send a **231,296 bytes** of raw audio data to server in following manner.

```
{
  "action": "start",
  "content-type": "audio/l16;rate=44100"
}

websocket.binary(true);
<bytes of binary audio data 50,000 bytes>
<bytes of binary audio data 50,000 bytes>
<bytes of binary audio data 50,000 bytes>
<bytes of binary audio data 50,000 bytes>
<bytes of binary audio data 31,296 bytes>

websocket.binary(false);
{
  "action": "stop"
}
```

Expected Result from IBMServer is :

```
 {"results": [
      {"alternatives": [
            {  "confidence": xxxx, 
               "transcript": "call Rohan Chauhan "
            }],"final": true
      }], "result_index": 0
}
```

> But I am not getting the desired result: **rather the error says**
>   "Broken pipe"

```
DataSize is: 50000 | mIsLast is : 0
DataSize is: 50000 | mIsLast is : 0
what : Broken pipe
DataSize is: 50000 | mIsLast is : 0
what : Operation canceled
DataSize is: 50000 | mIsLast is : 0
what : Operation canceled
DataSize is: 31296 | mIsLast is : 0
what : Operation canceled
```

> **Here is my code** which is an adaptation of the [sample example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async-ssl/websocket_client_async_ssl.cpp) given in beast library.

**Foo.hpp**

```
class IbmWebsocketSession: public std::enable_shared_from_this<IbmWebsocketSession> {
protected:
    char binarydata[50000];
    std::string TextStart;
    std::string TextStop;

public:
    explicit IbmWebsocketSession(net::io_context& ioc, ssl::context& ctx, SttService* ibmWatsonobj) :
        mResolver(ioc), mWebSocket(ioc, ctx) {
    TextStart ="{\"action\":\"start\",\"content-type\": \"audio/l16;rate=44100\"}";
    TextStop = "{\"action\":\"stop\"}";


   /**********************************************************************
    * Desc  : Send start frame
   **********************************************************************/
    void send_start(beast::error_code ec);
   /**********************************************************************
    * Desc  : Send Binary data
   **********************************************************************/
    void send_binary(beast::error_code ec);
   /**********************************************************************
    * Desc  : Send Stop frame
   **********************************************************************/
    void send_stop(beast::error_code ec);
   /**********************************************************************
    * Desc  : Read the file for binary data to be sent
   **********************************************************************/
    void readFile(char *bdata, unsigned int *Len, unsigned int *start_pos,bool *ReachedEOF);
}
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
void IbmWebsocketSession::on_ssl_handshake(beast::error_code ec) {
    if(ec)
        return fail(ec, "connect");
// Perform the websocket handshake
    ws_.async_handshake_ex(host, "/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize", [Token](request_type& reqHead) {reqHead.insert(http::field::authorization,Token);},bind(&IbmWebsocketSession::send_start, shared_from_this(),placeholders::_1));
}

void IbmWebsocketSession::send_start(beast::error_code ec){
    if(ec)
        return fail(ec, "ssl_handshake");

    ws_.async_write(net::buffer(TextStart),
        bind(&IbmWebsocketSession::send_binary, shared_from_this(),placeholders::_1));
}

void IbmWebsocketSession::send_binary(beast::error_code ec) {
    if(ec)
        return fail(ec, "send_start");
    readFile(binarydata, &Datasize, &StartPos, &IsLast);

    ws_.binary(true);
    if (!IsLast) {
        ws_.async_write(net::buffer(binarydata, Datasize),
            bind(&IbmWebsocketSession::send_binary, shared_from_this(),
                    placeholders::_1));

    } else {
        IbmWebsocketSession::on_binarysent(ec);
    }
}

void IbmWebsocketSession::on_binarysent(beast::error_code ec) {
    if(ec)
        return fail(ec, "send_binary");

    ws_.binary(false);
    ws_.async_write(net::buffer(TextStop),
           bind(&IbmWebsocketSession::read_response, shared_from_this(), placeholders::_1));
}

void IbmWebsocketSession::readFile(char *bdata, unsigned int *Len, unsigned int *start_pos,bool *ReachedEOF) {

    unsigned int end = 0;
    unsigned int start = 0;
    unsigned int length = 0;

    // Creation of ifstream class object to read the file
    ifstream infile(filepath, ifstream::binary);

    if (infile) {
        // Get the size of the file
        infile.seekg(0, ios::end);
        end = infile.tellg();

        infile.seekg(*start_pos, ios::beg);
        start = infile.tellg();

        length = end - start;
    }

    if ((size_t) length < 150) {
        *Len = (size_t) length;
        *ReachedEOF = true;
    // cout << "Reached end of File (last 150 bytes)" << endl;

    } else if ((size_t) length <= 50000) {  //Maximumbytes to send are 50000
        *Len = (size_t) length;
        *start_pos += (size_t) length;
        *ReachedEOF = false;
        infile.read(bdata, length);

    } else {
        *Len = 50000;
        *start_pos += 50000;
        *ReachedEOF = false;
        infile.read(bdata, 50000);
    }

    infile.close();
}
```

**Any suggestions here?**

Comment: Variables like `StartPos`, `IsLast` etc are declared in class.

Comment: Read about [boost::asio::buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html). You call `async_` with `buffer` created from local variables.. `async_` returns immediately. So `buffer` references to destroyed data.

Comment: @rafix07 I didn't quite understand your comment. Can you please elaborate? If not local what is it supposed to be? and are you talking only about `async_write(net::buffer(binarydata, Datasize)...` or all `async_write(net::buffer...`?

Comment: TextStart and mTextStop are local variables passed to async functions.

Comment: you can add `static` keyword in front of `TextStart` so its life time is infinitive. As @rafix07 points out, `buffer` is just a reference to data block, so values they point to have to have proper life times. Currently you have UB which sadly doesn't lead to a crash.

Comment: which version of C++ standard do you use?

Comment: @MarekR I am using c++11. And I have declared `static TextStart` & `static TextStop` in the class but the error persists. I am not sure what is causing this "Broken Pipe" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From boost's [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream/async_write.html) we have the following excerpt on `websocket::async_write`

> This function is used to asynchronously write a complete message. This
>   call always returns immediately. The asynchronous operation will
>   continue until one of the following conditions is true:
>
> 1. The complete message is written.
> 2. An error occurs.

So when you create your buffer object to pass to it `net::buffer(TextStart)` for example the lifetime of the `buffer` passed to it is only until the function returns. It could be that even after the function returns you the async write is still operating on the buffer as per the documentation but the contents are no longer valid since the `buffer` was a local variable.

To remedy this you could, make your `TextStart` static or declare that as a member of your class and copy it to [boost::asio::buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html) there are plenty of examples on how to do that. Note I only mention TextStart in the `IbmWebsocketSession::send_start` function. The problem is pretty much the same throughout your code.

From IBM Watson's [API definition](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/websockets.html#WSstart), the Initiate a connection requires a certain format which can then be represented as a string. You have the string but missing the proper format due to which the connection is being closed by the peer and you are writing to a closed socket, thus a broken pipe.

The initiate connection requires :

```
  var message = {
    action: 'start',
    content-type: 'audio/l16;rate=22050'
  };
```

Which can be represented as `string TextStart = "action: 'start',\r\ncontent-type: 'audio\/l16;rate=44100'"` according to your requirements.

Following on from the discussion in the chat, the OP resolved the issue by adding the code:

```
if (!IsLast ) {
    ws_.async_write(net::buffer(binarydata, Datasize),
    bind(&IbmWebsocketSession::send_binary, shared_from_this(),
    placeholders::_1));
} 
else {
     if (mIbmWatsonobj->IsGstFileWriteDone()) { //checks for the file write completion
         IbmWebsocketSession::on_binarysent(ec);
     } else {
         std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
         IbmWebsocketSession::send_binary(ec);
     }
}
```

Which from discussion stems from the fact that more bytes were being sent to the client before a file write was completed on the same set of bytes. The OP now verifies this before attempting to send more bytes.

Comment: I did try making both `TextStart` and `TextStop` static. But I faced the same problem. I tried making them member variable of class and then set the required text in the constructor. Still got the same broken Pipes.

Comment: Kindly check now the updated code snippet. But the error is still same

Comment: `std::string mTextStop = "{\"action\":\"stop\"}";` still a local variable

Comment: Ohh no my bad. forgot to remove it from there. Also I tried with adding static keyword in `.hpp` and the n declatring them in `.cpp` as `std::string IbmWebsocketSession::TextStart;` and similar for `TextStop`. no change

Comment: Now would be a good time to debug. Try commenting out functionality starting from the `handshake` down to the `send_start` and to the `send_binary`, to see which function is causing a broken pipe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191029/discussion-between-rc0993-and-samer-tufail).

Comment: can you confirm your `handshake` is working and is being authorized because I do not see the auth token being passed in. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53864065/how-to-connect-to-particular-endpoint-on-wss-ibm-watson for details.

Comment: It is pass and being authorized. I have deliberately omitted that part in this question to avoid that question.`ws_.async_handshake_ex(host, "/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize",[mToken](request_type& reqHead) {reqHead.insert(http::field::authorization,Token);},bind...);` where `Token` is the string "Bearer _{authtoken}_"

Comment: can you check the datasize before your send?

Comment: Yes. You can see that in the question `DataSize is: 50000 ...`. I am sending minimum of 150 bytes. if it is less than that, EOF is reached. I go on to `on_binarysent`

Comment: [lets move this to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191029/discussion-between-rc0993-and-samer-tufail)

Comment: Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55530669/how-does-beast-async-read-work-is-there-an-option-for-it)